# Python server problems

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

I created a simple server and client using Python. When i run it on my computer i works fine. But if i run the server on my comupter and try to open client on the other computer, it cant find my server. 
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the IP for your server computer? Just making sure you know that `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`) no longer works in this setup.

Are your computers behind a NAT?

Can you `ping` from one computer to another?

Do you have a firewall?

Answer (score 0):

For BaseHTTPServer http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html you will want to pass in the empty string `''` as the server address.